# building combination table out of classic order

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I would like to built a combination table for example 4 number of 5 samples(0 -4), but not in the right order. The table should start with the combinations of 0 and 1; than 0,1 2; than 0,1,2,3; than 0,1,2,3,4. Of course the table should not have repetition.  I need an algorithm to do it but I can not find any until now. After that I have to write a java code. At the end the table should look like this:

```
0   0   0   1
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   0
0   1   1   1
....    ... ... ...
1   1   1   1
0   0   0   2
....    ... ... ...
2   0   0   0
... ... ... ...
0   0   1   2
....    ... ... ...
2   2   2   2
0   0   0   3
....    ... ... ...
3   0   0   0
0   0   1   3
....    ... ... ...
3   2   2   2
... ... ... ...
3   3   3   3
....    ....    ......  ...
4   4   4   4
```

Comment: *"I need an algorithm.."*  You need to show some effort.  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.  Also, given this is a Q&A forum, it would not hurt to add a *question.*

Comment: You are saying I have to do this, I have to do that, then why dont u do something about it. I mean its not written SO have to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could start with `0000` and increment by 1 (in base 2,3,4,5) until you overflow. E.g.

### Base 2:

```
0000 + 1 => 0001
0001 + 1 => 0010
0010 + 1 => 0011
...
1110 + 1 => 1111
```

### Base 3:

```
0000 + 1 => 0001
0001 + 1 => 0002
0002 + 1 => 0010
...
2221 + 1 => 2222
```

And similar for bases 4 and 5.

If you care about repeats (e.g. `0001` is repeated in base 2 and 3) then you can just increment until: for base 2 you have at least a single 1, for base 3 you have at least a single `2`, etc...

---

### Java Example:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int n = 4;

    // for base 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (base 1 gives 0000)
    for(int base = 1; base < n + 2; base++)

        // for every combination: base^n
        for(int j = 0; j < Math.pow(base, n); j++)

            // if num contains a (base-1) digit, it's not a dup
            if(Integer.toString(j, base).contains(Integer.toString(base-1)))
                System.out.println(String.format("%04d",
                    Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(j, base))));
}
```

Comment: But that does repeat combinations, for example `0001`.

Comment: Ok. That is pretty nice. And what about the condition of not repetition. How  to write it.

Comment: that's already taken care of in the "Java Example." Check out the if statement.